# Denoiser slows rendering too much

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, denoise

Suzanne on transparent background with 1 sample and denoiser is rendering slower than at 100 samples and no denoiser. PC specs: Ryzen7 1700 (stock), GTX 1050ti, Win10 64bit

**v.2.79a, CPU+GPU, 1980p, 64px tile:**

1. 1 sample + denoiser (radius 10) - 00:40:35
2. 100 samples - 00:12:47

What is wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong, the denoising takes time, that's all.

In your blend, most of the area has literally nothing. The renderer notices that and renders those areas *extremely* fast. The denoiser still has to treat all the pixels, and does not know that there is nothing there.

As an exemple (CPU only, render size changed to 1080x1080):
100 samples, no denoise:
your file, ('as is') : ~11s  (GPU 6s)
with added background plane : ~33 s (GPU: 24s)

1 sample, default denoise settings:
your file, ('as is') : ~25s (GPU: 9s)
with added backgound : ~26 s (GPU: 10s)
(render of 1 sample w/o denoise takes <1s, with or w/o background)

I'm not going to give all the results, but for this scene, the denoising seems to add ~25s to the processing on CPU (on my system, and with the reduced output size!), independent of the presence of a background plane or the number of samples.

Comment: Then I guess, I am misunderstanding conception of denoiser. Is it more intended to remove fireflies where you can't increase sampling (because it is already high) rather than perform a cheaty way to keep clean render and cut some extra time by lowering sample amount?

Comment: Well, denoising is an extra processing step, with associated costs, which are *constant *for a given situation, and it's efficient. But, to halve your noise, you'd need to use 4x the n° of samples. Your sample scene is extremely simple, so doesn't require many samples. For some scenes (interiors), I've seen sample counts of 1000s, there the denoiser is very useful.